# Cambiar formato numeric a h:mm:ss para visualización SQL

Tags: sql

Necesitaría de vuestra experiencia y ayuda para intentar sacar el siguiente campo en formato h:mm:ss.

El campo en cuestión es numhoras donde el usuario alimenta 0,50, 1,00 (siendo 0:30:00, 1:00:00...) en el formato deseado(h:mm:ss).

Estoy intentando realizar un `convert` y `floor` pero me representa erróneamente el valor, ya que el resultado de la hora me lo pinta en el minuto (0:01:00)
La query seria la siguiente:

```
select
    codigo_Av,
    (tbcursos.numhoras) as horas,
    tbgrupos.inicio as fechainicio,
    CONVERT(varchar(4), FLOOR(tbCursos.NumHoras / 60)) + ':' + RIGHT(
        '00' + CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR(tbCursos.NumHoras % 60)),
        2
    ) + ':' + RIGHT(
        '00' + CONVERT(
            varchar(10),
            FLOOR(
                (tbCursos.NumHoras - FLOOR(tbCursos.NumHoras)) * 60
            )
        ),
        2
    ) [time_string]
from
    tbcursos
    inner join tbInscripciones on dbo.tbCursos.idCurso = dbo.tbInscripciones.idCurso
    inner join tbempleados on dbo.tbInscripciones.idEmpleado = dbo.tbEmpleados.idEmpleado
    inner join tbgrupos on tbinscripciones.idgrupo = tbgrupoS.idgrupo
where
    tbinscripciones.asistio = 'Si'
    and tbgrupos.inicio >= '01/10/2018'
group by
    codigo_av,
    (tbcursos.numhoras),
    tbgrupos.inicio
```

el resultado que muestra esta query el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ante todo gracias previas por vuestro tiempo intentando ayudarme a esta cuestión
Gracias!!

Comment: Hola Victor.
El campo numhoras siempre se llenará solamente por salto de 0.50?
Es decir 0.50, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50

Comment: Buenos días!!, no siempre se rellena en salto, puede ser 0,75... gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creando una fecha cualquiera con la función `datetimefromparts()` usando horas y minutos. Y después darle formato:

```
SELECT format( datetimefromparts(2000,1,1,floor(tbCursos.numHoras),(tbCursos.numHoras-floor(tbCursos.numHoras))*60,0,0)
             , 'HH:mm:ss'
             )
  FROM ...
```

Comment: Buenos días , al intentar lanzar esta función me indica que datetimeformparts no es un nombre de función integrada reconocida

Comment: ¿Cuál motor de base de datos y versión usas?

Comment: Parece que tienes la R y la O invertidos.

Comment: utilizo esta: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64)   Aug 19 2014 12:21:34   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)